# useSelector в RTK возвращает undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Тут использую `useSelector`: https://codesandbox.io/s/11-q57xgf?file=/src/App.tsx,
Так выглядит `store`: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-violet-vnwnp4?file=/src/App.tsx,
Так выглядит сам `slice`: https://codesandbox.io/s/33-gdjxzh?file=/src/App.tsx,
Так выглядит второй `slice` из `store`(если нужно): https://codesandbox.io/s/44-7vndsd?file=/src/App.tsx

Когда навожу мышкой, показывает, что внутри есть 2 `slice`, а когда запрашиваю `headerMenuBtn` из `store`, то приходит `undefined`.

Если в консоль логе запросить (`state`) => `state`, то в state только 1 `slice`, а headerMenuBtn отсутствует в нем. `useSelector` не видит второй `slice`, хотя он добавлен в `store`.

Answer (score 0):

На случай, если кто-то тоже столкнется с этим:

Была обертка `<ApiProvider>`, она блокировала обычный `<Provider>`. Должна быть либо та либо та обертка.